# Check DB int field against timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

iam saving a date to my database as timestamp ( int field )

Now i have an external date in my php which i convert also into timestamp to compare it later.
I must make the check in the query, i cant select the date from the db before to compare them afterwards

**What i need:**
I wanna see if the external date is same date as the stored int value. the compare should only cover yyyy-mm-dd

little example.

my external date is 2011-02-23, which is only present without hours, the stored timestamp is lets say 123747382

What would a mysql query where clause look like, or what php am i missing in order to know that both stamps are the same date?

```
$r_date = '2011-02-23';
$stamp_day = strtotime($r_date);

WHERE addtime = '{$stamp_day}'
```

addtime would be the stored timestamp in the int field

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
"WHERE DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `addtime` ) ) = '$r_date'"
```

or:

```
"WHERE DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `addtime` ) ) = DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( '$stamp_day' ) )"
```

Comment: FROM_UNIXTIME('$stamp_day', '%Y-%D-%M') might also work without DATE(), not sure. Havent tested it